# City public transport routes application

Tags: android, localization, dictionary, routes

I've decided to make an Android localization application for my diploma and now I'm thinking about its functionality. I want my application to store my city's public transport routes and to draw them on the map. I'm kinda new to Android localization mechanisms and I don't really now, if it's possible to implement. Here are some questions I'd like to ask:

- How can I store routes?
- How can I draw them?
- Is it possible to localize a route that crosses a certain point on the map?

Any links to posts, documentation, sources will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've decided to make an Android localization application

I fail to see how anything here relates to [localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localization) as the term tends to be used in software development. If you have a different definition of that term in mind, you may wish to edit your question and provide your definition.

> How can I store routes?

Store them in a file. That could be in whatever file format you get them in from your city (to simplify synchronization) or in some converted format (to simplify rendering).

> How can I draw them?

You failed to indicate what you are using for maps. There are multiple mapping solutions for Android.

Assuming that you intend to use the Google Maps add-on for Android, you would create a subclass of [`Overlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) and override `draw()` to render your routes, using a [`Projection`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection.html) to convert between latitude/longitude and pixel coordinates.

> Is it possible to localize a route that crosses a certain point on the map?

I would think that your route's location labels would already be [localized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localization) to your language and city culture from the data you obtain from the city.